# Azure Data Studio

Tags: sql, database, azure

I encounter the following error when I'm trying to connect to a Microsoft SQL server with Azure Data Studio through Docker container: 'A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server: Could not open a connection to SQL Server)'

I doubt that server is down because I have tried it before on a different device and worked properly. Can someone point out what might be the error related to ?

Thank you

I tried connecting to the same server with both Terminal and UI and both resulted the same.

Comment: The firewall might block you

Comment: Once check with the network while connecting.

Comment: In SQL Configuration manager for tcp connection make sure dynamic port is blank as opposed to 0.  0 is on, blank is off, seriously!  Double check both the ip you are using and IPALL at the bottom!

Answer (score 0):

**The Error you are facing may be few different reasons.**

**To resolve this you can follow below steps:**

- Check the `servername` and `credential` you are using to connect the database if you used wrong names.
- Check the IP of your client machine is whitelisted on firewall settings of azure SQL.
- Check The port is proper enabled on your machine.

Refer this [MS document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/connect/network-related-or-instance-specific-error-occurred-while-establishing-connection) for more information.

Comment: Please do not post AI-generated text pretending you wrote it. This is forbidden on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @tchrist it's not AI generated I referd the doc I provided in answer and wrote the important points which can leads to the above error. If it seems that it is AI generated, I will update the answer soon.